# Failed Integration Test of the “remember me” Checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies, railstutorial.org

I am following **railstutorial.org 3rd Edition** and I am currently working on **Chapter 8: Log in, log out**.

I found an issue in Listing 8.51 (login without remembering test):

```
assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
```

When I execute: `rake test`, it's return RED with the following error:

```
FAIL["test_login_without_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 1.268578948]
 test_login_without_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1.27s)
    Expected "" to be nil.
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:46:in `block in      <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Otherwise, when I change to the following code, it is returning GREEN and the Log In - Log out process work properly.

```
assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
```

Anyone who faces the same issue can explain this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Where's the code being tested, or at least the link to this exercise you're doing?

Comment: @rockskull I am following tutorial in this [link](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_tests) (8.4.6 point) and my code is exactly the same as in that tutorial. But, when i run test in Listing 8.52, it is return RED.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just made this mistake...

TL;DR; remove `remember user` from `sessions_controller.rb`

---

Take a look at [Listing 8.34](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out).
You should find 
`remember user`
in the `session_controller.rb`.

Now in reference to the same file, take a look at [Listing 8.49](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out).
The author makes a big deal about this line, but if you just paste it in without removing the call to `remember user`, the token will still get generated.

So, when pasting in this line:

`params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)`

make sure it is replacing the call to `remember user`.